# error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined while getting value of input in section element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm newbie in world of JS I'm stuck at error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
```

I have two `<section>` elements say

```
<section id = "sec-1">                 
    <textarea id="firstName" ></textarea>        
</section>  
<section id = "sec-2">                 
    <textarea id="firstName"></textarea>        
</section>
```

in following script I want to get the value of `<textarea>` as

```
var firstNameTextValue = $("#sec-" + n +" input").attr("id").$("#firstName").val();
```

but getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: You have a syntax error...JS interpreter will look for method `$` of `$("#sec-" + n +" input").attr("id")`

Comment: Yes I'm getting error at `$("#firstName").val();`, how can I get value from that in put using its Id?

Comment: first all `id` should  be unique, then you can get value by `var firstNameTextValue = $("#sec-" + n +" input").val();`

Comment: @PranavCBalan there should not allow different `id` for `<textarea id="firstName"></textarea>` in my case...

Comment: `attr("id")` returns a `string` or `undefined` and then you are trying to get `$` property of it, which is undefined

Comment: Two `textarea` have same `id`

Comment: @guradio, That is __$ is not defined__

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` yeah i had to check it make sure it same and its not @RayonDabre

Comment: @RayonDabre beat me to it by 1 sec :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Close. `attr("id")` returns `undefined`, not empty string, given that there is no `input` elements; `undefined.$` produces the error.

Comment: @Amadan : yup , my mistake.... it's in the error log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
var firstNameTextValue = $("#sec-" + n +" input").attr("id").$("#firstName").val();
```

use

```
var firstNameTextValue = $("#sec-" + n +" textarea[id='firstName']").val()
```

where the value of n should 1 or 2 so that it will select appropriate `section` and you also need find `textarea` not `input` in side the `section` as you have not used `input type='text'`, you have used `textarea` for user inputs